# JavaScript control flow with multiple REST APIs?

Tags: javascript, rest

I'm writing a SharePoint code to create a new folder and upload multiple files there. In pseudo C code, it would look like this.

```
String  folderName = giveNiceFolderNameBasedOnSomeBusinessLogic();

if(REST_checkfileExists(folderName) {
    if(confirmDialog("File already exists. Do you want to delete old folder ?") == true) {
        REST_deleteFile(folderName)
    } else {
        return;     // Do not overwrite
    }
}
if(REST_createFolder(folderName) == 0) {
    REST_uploadFiles( folderName, fileListToUpload);
}
```

Below is my ingredients in JavaScript collected over google searches.
I confirm each function works in my environment, but couldn't figure out how I can glue them while keeping each function re-usable. I appreciate experts' advise here.

http://codejaw.com/yezime

For example, I can hardcode the next step inside the REST_deleteFile() function to go to REST_uploadFiles(), as that's the only control path with the above pseudo code.

However, once I hardcode it, apparently, I cannot use the REST_deleteFile() function
for other purposes. I'm hoping there is a better way to address this.

Thanks for your help in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to just omit the hardcoded part is to pass callback function as a second parameter. In that way you can make the function more reusable and do whatever you want when the request was successfull.

```
function REST_deleteFile(filePathName, onSuccess) {
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var webRelUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
    var fullUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + webRelUrl + filePathName + "')";

    $.ajax({
        url: fullUrl,
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE",
            "IF-MATCH": "*"
        },
        success: onSuccess,
        error:function() {
            console.log("Fail to delete the file :" + filePathName );
        }
    });


REST_deleteFile('path/to/file', REST_createFolder(filePathName))
```

Comment: Thank you ! This works and easy enough for me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The api calls in JS are asynchronous, your function `REST_checkFileExists` is not returning anything means `undefine` so if block will not execute. Similarly for function `REST_createFolder` wil return `undefine`. Again `undefine == 0` is `false`. 
In order for this code to work. You need to change your functions structure using [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) or [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) chain.

Comment: Please read how to use `fetch()`, as this method now more standardized than ajax. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

You may use promises or async/await. These days callbacks are generally not as popular, but that's still possible.

Comment: Thank you. With my current JavaScript experience, too many "=>" brings me beyond my comfort zone :( But definitely, I keep this in my learning list to revisit.